# Javascript: Change images in a webpge

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I have a web page that I want to be able to have one location for an image and then on click a bit of text it changes to another image.

I have tried this code, but I cannot get this to work:

```js
function ChangeImage(fileName) {
  let img = document.querySelector('#bannerImage');
  img.setAttribute('src', fileName);

}
```

```html
<img id="bannerImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x100" width="600" />
<br />
<br />
<button onClick="changeimage('image1.jpg')">Image 1</button>
<button onClick="changeimage('image2.jpg')">Image 2</button>
<button onClick="changeimage('image3.jpg')">Image 3</button>
```

Also instead of buttons I'd prefer some text for example:

```
|
<a href="#" onClick="changeimage('image1.jpg')">Image One</a> | 
<a href="#" onClick="changeimage('image2.jpg')">Image One</a> |
<a href="#" onClick="changeimage('image3.jpg')">Image One</a> |
```

Thanks for any help you can give me

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. Don't add tags.

Comment: Check your browser's development console for errors.  What you have is simply a typo.  `ChangeImage` and `changeimage` are not the same thing.

Comment: Regarding your second question, links should not be used as buttons. You can style buttons to appear as plain text if you prefer. Also, don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not their purpose. Use margin, padding, block-level wrappers, flex properties, etc.